# Is it possible to convert a DOM element to a string and back?

Tags: javascript, string, function, dom, element

I am getting any DOM element (document.body for instance) and I want to convert it to a String like so:

```
function convert(el){
//should return a String
}

alert(convert(document.body));
//should alert (String) "document.body"
alert(document.getElementById('foo'));
//should alert (String) "document.getElementById('foo')"
```

I also want to convert those strings back (if possible not using eval()). For example:

```
function convertBack(el){
//should return a node
}

convertBack('document.body').innerHTML = 'foo';
//should change the innerHTML of document.body to foo
```

This may seem useless to some of you, but this my approach for a workaround to target elements, that don't yet exist. I am not using any library.

Thanks!

Comment: You litterly want to have 'document.body'? And just out of curiosity, why do you want this?

Comment: Yes, not [object HTMLBodyElement]. I want to target DOM elements as source code if that makes sense to you...

Comment: if you include your initial issue, there might be a better/easier approach

Comment: This sounds a lot like an X Y problem.

Comment: Honestly it kind of is. However, a lot of JavaScript libraries can target DOM elements like that so I am sure there's some way.

Comment: So then maybe ask the question you're trying to solve, and provide your thoughts on solving the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Using standard JavaScript, with `e` as an element:

Converting to a string:

```js
const html = e.outerHTML
```

Converting back to an element:

```js
const temp = document.createElement('div') // Can be any element
temp.innerHTML = html
const e = temp.children[0]
```

With jQuery it is very easy, although I discourage its use in general.

Converting to string:

```js
var s = e.outerHTML;
```

Converting back to an element:

```js
var e = $(s)[0];
```

`$("<div></div>")` parses the HTML and returns a jQuery object. You can obtain a reference to the first element with `[0]`

Comment: I am not using jQuery, but this would certainly work for some elements. Thanks anyway.